# ASP.net page life cycle with examples

Tags: asp.net

I was looking for ASP.net page life cycle events tutorial using examples. 
I saw MSDN but did not understand. Any link please with examples?

Comment: are you referring to asp.net or webforms? They are two different frameworks.

Comment: What examples are you expecting? I think that this page is very detailed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx
Do you have a concrete question? Maybe you find following video helpful: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-35-applications/page-lifecycle-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link [Page Life Cycle in Asp.Net](http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/performance/page-life-cycle-asp.aspx), its goes in detail to explain the methods and gives description. Best thing to do is picture in your head the calls being made!

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2006/06/30/Complete+Lifecycle+Of+An+ASPNet+Page+And+Controls.aspx#pg

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETPageLifecycle.aspx